# Karp hardness of a simply equidistant vertex set

Tags: np-complete, np-hard, np

Following the success of the previous question:

[Karp hardness of an equidistant vertex set](https://cs.stackexchange.com/questions/97633/karp-hardness-of-an-equidistant-vertex-set)

I continue to propse yet another computational problem. This time, we modify the notion of an equidistant vertex set to obtain the notion of a **simply equidistant vertex set**. A vertex set $V'\subseteq V$ is called *simply equidistant* if there exists some $\alpha\in \mathbb{N}$ such that for every $u, v\in V'$, there exists a *simple path* of length $\alpha$ connecting $u$, $v$.

Our problem:

> Input: an undirected graph $G(V,E)$ and a natural number $k$
>
> Output: **YES** if there exists a simply equidistant of size $k$,
>   otherwise **NO**

What is the hardness of this problem?